# Android or Linux + Electron for consumer facing GUI

Tags: linux, android

I’m looking to build a consumer facing IoT product that involves a display. I have been debating whether to use Android or Linux + Electron for the app, which will be running kiosk style all the time. What is the general rule of thumb for this kind of decision/pros and cons? The display can be touchscreen or not, doesn’t matter. Primary navigation is via voice control

Comment: Hey welcome to the site!  Unfortunately your question is really opinion based as it stands... in order for this to be a good fit for this site, you'll have to [edit] it to show what research you've done, what your requirements are for the project, and exactly where your uncertainty lies.  Thanks!